# How to use constructor in Java

Tags: java

Can someone please tell me what's wrong with this simple program? I'm getting output as "0".

```
package myConst;

public class Doconstructor
{
    int length,width;

    Doconstructor(int x, int y)
    {
        int area;
        area = length * width;
        System.out.println("area ="+area);
    }
}

class work
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Doconstructor d1 = new Doconstructor(10, 15);
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't set length or width.

Comment: length and width will always be 0, since they are never initialized. In that case, set length = x and width = y, and then use both of them. A good practice would be to observe the code before u could depend on anyone for help. self help is the best help ever :)

Comment: If you didn't assign any values to `length` or `width`, why are you surprised that they are 0? The program does exactly what you tell it to do. :)

Comment: By the way, I'm not sure why this question is getting downvotes. While it is a basic question, it is a valid question with compilable code (it was actually somebody else who inadvertently edited out a closing brace -- @sashkello please be mindful of edits) and a fairly clear, albeit brief, description of the problem and results.

Comment: @JasonC whoops, sorry, my bad with the edit. I didn't downvote though, but the downvotes are understandable as this is debugging through SO - the question goes away as soon as you simply print things after each code iteration.

Comment: @sashkello Fair enough, that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

```
Doconstructor d1 = new Doconstructor(10, 15);
// you are assigning values for x and y
```

But

```
Doconstructor (int x,int y)
{ 
    int area;            // you are never use x and y values for calculation
    area = length *width; // so area remain 0 since current length and width is 0
    System.out.println("area ="+area);
}
```

You need to change your code as follows.

```
Doconstructor (int x,int y)
{
    int area;
    this.length=x;
    this.width=y;
    area = length *width;
    System.out.println("area ="+area);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit like this:-

```
 package myConst;

    public class Doconstructor
    {
        int length,width;

        Doconstructor(int x, int y)
        {
            int area;
    this.length=x;//Using this for current object
    this.width=y;//Using this for current object
            area = length * width;
            System.out.println("area ="+area);
        }
    }

    class work
    {
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            Doconstructor d1 = new Doconstructor(10, 15);
        }
    }
```

Your output will be:

**area =150**

Must read this :

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the values of `length` and `width` and by default they are both `0`. You might have to do this:

```
Doconstructor(int x, int y){
   int area;
   area = x * y;
   length = x;
   width = y;
   System.out.println("Area = "+area);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the variable values you pass to the constructor in it but rather the length and width values that have been initialized to 0. You want `area = x * y;` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The length and width fields are implicitly initialized to 0. Multiply them and you get 0.

I think what you want is

```
length = y ;
width = x ;
int area = length * width ;
System.out.println("area ="+area);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this:

```
public class Doconstructor {

    int length,width;

    Doconstructor (int x,int y)
    {
        int area;
        area = length *width;
        System.out.println("area ="+area);
    }
}
```

At no point do you set `length` or `width` equal to anything. Their initial values are 0 and your program is doing precisely what you told it to do. `area = length * width = 0 * 0 = 0`.

You also are not doing anything with the `x` or `y` that you passed to the constructor, but this probably was not your intention. When writing programs, you basically need to clearly instruct the computer to do what you want to do. It's not going to guess what you want. If you ignore `x` and `y`, and don't assign any values to `length` or `width`, then that is precisely what will happen and you cannot be surprised when you see the results you see.

Answer (score 0):

you are writing `int length,width` at class level so length and width are set to 0 as default.
After that in the constructor you are not setting any values to length and width so you are the values for length and width are 0.Hence area is also 0
Please check this link for list of [default values](http://web.archive.org/web/20120212170313/http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#96595)

Answer (score 0):

Constructors are used to create objects and to set the attributes. You are not setting the attributes in your constructor.  Here is how your constructor should look like.

```
Doconstructor(int x, int y){
   length = x;
   width = y;
}
```

Secondly you are mixing the logic of a constructor and a method. You are doing the calculation of area, which seems to be a perfect fit for another method in your class. so better move that logic in a separate method:

```
public int calculateArea() {
   int area;
   area = x * y;
   return area;
}
```

Finally create an object using constructor to set the attributes length and width. And then call calculateArea method to do the business logic of calculating area.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Doconstructor d1 = new Doconstructor(10, 15); // create object and set length & width
     d1.calculateArea();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not assigning the value of x and y to the variables width and length. The default value of width and length are (int) 0. Thats why you are getting the output (0*0=0). First assign the values to the variables or use "area=x*y;" .